# One of the factor's levels is an empty string; how to replace it with non-missing value?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

Data frame AEbySOC contains two columns - factor SOC with character levels and integer count Count:

```
> str(AEbySOC)
'data.frame':   19 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SOC  : Factor w/ 19 levels "","Blood and lymphatic system disorders",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Count: int  25 50 7 3 1 49 49 2 1 9 ...
```

One of the levels of SOC is an empty character string:

```
> l = levels(AEbySOC$SOC)
> l[1]
[1] ""
```

I want to replace the value of this level by a non-empty string, say, "Not specified". This does not work:

```
> library(plyr)
> revalue(AEbySOC$SOC, c(""="Not specified"))
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Neither does this:

```
> AEbySOC$SOC[AEbySOC$SOC==""] = "Not specified"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, AEbySOC$SOC == "", value = c(NA, 2L, 3L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

What's the right way to implement this? I appreciate any input/comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
levels(AEbySOC$SOC)[1] <- "Not specified"
```

Created a toy example:

```
df<- data.frame(a= c("", "a", "b"))

df
#  a
#1  
#2 a
#3 b

levels(df$a)
#[1] ""  "a" "b"

levels(df$a)[1] <- "Not specified"

levels(df$a)
#[1] "Not specified" "a"             "b"
```

**EDIT**

As per the OP's comments if we need to find it according the value then in such case, we can try

```
levels(AEbySOC$SOC)[levels(AEbySOC$SOC) == ""] <- "Not specified"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should work:

```
test <- data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "", "  "))
str(test)

which.one <- which( levels(test$a) == "" )
levels(test$a)[which.one] <- "NA"
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(SOC = c("", "a", "b"))

df <- df %>% 
   mutate(SOC = fct_recode(SOC, "Not specified" = ""))
```

Which results in:

```
            SOC
1 Not specified
2             a
3             b
```

Comment: Very nice! This one would be close to beat Ronak's solution in CodeGolf :) However, your option requires additional package installed.