# Replacing empty values with plyr::revalue

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a vector in which I want to replace some values, based on another vector.

I use `plyr::revalue` for this :

```
x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "", "  ", "d, ", "aaaaa")
var.replace = c("d"=NA, "a"="A")
x %>%  plyr::revalue(var.replace)
#[1] "A"      "b"      "c"      NA       ""       "  "     "d, "    "aaaaa"
var.replace = c("d"=NA, "a"="A", ""=NA)
#Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

I know there is an accepted answer in the question [One of the factor's levels is an empty string; how to replace it with non-missing value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370738/one-of-the-factors-levels-is-an-empty-string-how-to-replace-it-with-non-missin), but I'm looking for an elegant one-liner, in the tidyverse spirit.

Does one exists ?

Comment: Maybe something like `replace(x, x == '', NA) %>% plyr::revalue(var.replace)`?

Comment: Isn't this easier with`na.strings` while reading i.e. the `""` and `"d"`

Comment: @akrun I cannot, because the database is lame and empty string are sometimes `NA` and sometimes `0`.

Comment: But If you set the empty to become NA with `na.strings`, then wouldn't it be easier to revalue 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akrun answer made me figure it out ! It happens that you just have to omit the key for the name to be empty :

```
> setNames(c(NA, "A", NA), c("d", "a", ""))
#  d   a     
# NA "A"  NA 
> c("d"=NA, "a"="A", NA)
#  d   a     
# NA "A"  NA
```

Then, the formula become very simple :

```
var.replace = c("d"=NA, "a"="A", NA)
x %>%  revalue(var.replace)
```

Comment: That is better!  We were all chasing that `""`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace` to deal with empty elements and then revalue as usual, i.e.

```
replace(x, x == '', NA) %>% plyr::revalue(var.replace)
#[1] "A"     "b"     "c"     NA      NA      "  "    "d, "   "aaaaa"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `setNames` to create `""` as names and then do the `revalue`

```
var.replace <- setNames(c(NA, "A", NA), c("d", "a", ""))
x %>%
    plyr::revalue(var.replace)
#[1] "A"     "b"     "c"     NA      NA      "  "    "d, "   "aaaaa"
```

Comment: Interesting solution. akrun at his best.